# external database connection on web host not working

Tags: java, android

i followed a tutorial of login/register on android studio (toni kami tutorial) , i did all of what he did , but the httpclient /httpparams method is no longer working on android studio , im new to app programming so i searched the internet for a way to work this problem , i found a url connection code , i copy it but its not working .

****** this is all the java class ******
------ help me by correcting this or give me a new idea to work it out ------
when i run the app i get this :

```html
package com.thenewboston.loginr;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by sleeman on 1/1/16.
 */
public class ServerRequests {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
    public static  final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://sleemanb94.tk/";

    public  ServerRequests(Context context){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");

    }

    public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user, getUserCallBack userCallback){
        progressDialog.show();
        new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user,userCallback).execute();
    }

    public void fetchUserDataInBackground(User user, getUserCallBack callback) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, callback).execute();

    }

    public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        User user;
        getUserCallBack userCallback;

        public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, getUserCallBack userCallback){
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Map<String,String> dataToSend = new HashMap<>();
            dataToSend.put("fname", user.fname);
            dataToSend.put("lname", user.lname);
            dataToSend.put("email", user.email);
            dataToSend.put("password", user.password);

            //Server Communication part - it's relatively long but uses standard methods

            //Encoded String - we will have to encode string by our custom method (Very easy)
            String encodedStr = getEncodedData(dataToSend);

            //Will be used if we want to read some data from server
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            //Connection Handling
            try {
                //Converting address String to URL
                URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");
                //Opening the connection (Not setting or using CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                //Post Method
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                //To enable inputting values using POST method
                //(Basically, after this we can write the dataToSend to the body of POST method)
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                //Writing dataToSend to outputstreamwriter
                writer.write(encodedStr);
                //Sending the data to the server - This much is enough to send data to server
                //But to read the response of the server, you will have to implement the procedure below
                writer.flush();

                //Data Read Procedure - Basically reading the data comming line by line
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Read till there is something available
                    sb.append(line + "\n");     //Reading and saving line by line - not all at once
                }
                line = sb.toString();           //Saving complete data received in string, you can do it differently

                //Just check to the values received in Logcat
                Log.i("custom_check", "The values received in the store part are as follows:");
                Log.i("custom_check",line);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();     //Closing the
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;

        }

        private String getEncodedData(Map<String,String> data) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(String key : data.keySet()) {
                String value = null;
                try {
                    value = URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key), "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(sb.length()>0)
                    sb.append("&");

                sb.append(key + "=" + value);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(null);

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

    public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
        User user;
        getUserCallBack userCallback;

        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, getUserCallBack userCallback) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;
        }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //Use HashMap, it works similar to NameValuePair
            Map<String, String> dataToSend = new HashMap<>();
            dataToSend.put("email", user.email);
            dataToSend.put("password", user.password);

            //Server Communication part - it's relatively long but uses standard methods

            //Encoded String - we will have to encode string by our custom method (Very easy)
            String encodedStr = getEncodedData(dataToSend);

            //Will be used if we want to read some data from server
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            //Connection Handling
            User returnedUser = null;
            try {
                //Converting address String to URL
                URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");
                //Opening the connection (Not setting or using CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                //Post Method
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                //To enable inputting values using POST method
                //(Basically, after this we can write the dataToSend to the body of POST method)
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                //Writing dataToSend to outputstreamwriter
                writer.write(encodedStr);
                //Sending the data to the server - This much is enough to send data to server
                //But to read the response of the server, you will have to implement the procedure below
                writer.flush();

                //Data Read Procedure - Basically reading the data comming line by line
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Read till there is something available
                    sb.append(line + "\n");     //Reading and saving line by line - not all at once
                }
                line = sb.toString();           //Saving complete data received in string, you can do it differently

                //Just check to the values received in Logcat
                Log.i("custom_check", "The values received in the store part are as follows:");
                Log.i("custom_check", line);
                returnedUser = new User( user.fname, user.lname);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();     //Closing the
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnedUser;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(returnedUser);

            super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
        }

        private String getEncodedData(Map<String, String> data) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                String value = null;
                try {
                    value = URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key), "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (sb.length() > 0)
                    sb.append("&");

                sb.append(key + "=" + value);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Any have error or something ??? Let show more info about what you try

Comment: im new to app programming , i copy a code from a tutorial on youtube , but the connection method (httpclient) with a web host (that has the database) is no longer working , google and android decided to block that method , so i copied a url connection code , but its not working , i posted  all the code here and i hope you look at it and diagnose the problem , perhaps its a little problem .

Comment: maybe this tutorial can help you http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html#json_android

Comment: i will try it , thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` is deprecated. But you can use it in android studio easily

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34628866/4898620)